# How to allow multiple users read Letsencrypt Certificates

Tags: linux, lets-encrypt

I have one Ubuntu Server with LetsEncrypt certificates using two service

1- Apache
2- Kamailio

How can I allow TWO users to read SAME certificate, I don't want to move the location for each service because both services are running on same domain.

Thanks,

Comment: You should probably add a bit more information about your setup first: how are your certificates managed? Are you using an Apache module? Are you using an external tool like lego? What problems are you facing? After all, certificates are just regular files that can have any permissions that you set on them. And both services can be pointed to any certificate file that you want.

Comment: I m generating LetsEncryot SSL certificate through certbot so they r stored on default location /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN.COM/